# C# How to change a int value on another form (windows form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been trying to change an integer's value on a second form.
I have two forms. The first one is my main form. It contains the integer I'm trying to change. The second form is my option form. I need to change the integer's value on the first form using a numeric upDown on my second form. The problem is that each time I open the second form , it resets the first form.

Here is how I open the second form on the first form:

```
private void optionsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I need to access the second form
    frmOptions frmOptionsJeux = new frmOptions();
    frmOptionsJeux.Show(); 
}
```

Second Form code:

```
namespace TP3
{
    public partial class frmOptions : Form
    {
        // I need to access the first form
        frmPrincipal frmJeu = new frmPrincipal();


        public frmOptions()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            // Sets the value of the Numeric UpDowns (boiteNbLignes & boiteNbColonnes

            // nbLignesDansTableauDeJeu & nbColonnesDansTableauDeJeu are the two integers I need to modify.

            boiteNbLignes.Value = frmJeu.nbLignesDansTableauDeJeu;
            boiteNbColonnes.Value = frmJeu.nbColonnesDansTableauDeJeu;

        }

        //The integers are only modified when I click OK
        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AppliquerOptionsTaille();
            this.Hide();             
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

        // How the integers are supposed to be modified
        public void AppliquerOptionsTaille( )
        { 
            frmJeu.nbLignesDansTableauDeJeu = (int)boiteNbLignes.Value;
            frmJeu.nbColonnesDansTableauDeJeu = (int)boiteNbColonnes.Value;                  
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've been trying for at least 4 hours.
It's for a school project. Sorry for the french words in the code! (french school)

Comment: `frmPrincipal frmJeu = new frmPrincipal();` is creating a *new* first form. Changing anything on `frmJeu` is changing the property on this new, yet hidden, form. Have your `frmOptions` constructor take a `frmPrincipal`. Then call it like this: `frmOptions frmOptionsJeux = new frmOptions(this);`

Comment: Thanks ! , I still have a problem though. Calling AppliquerOptionsTaille is impossible. Here is what I did : public void AppliquerOptionsTaille(frmPrincipal frmJeu )

Comment: But I can't put anything between () when calling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create second form pass refference to your first one:

```
frmOptions frmOptionsJeux = new frmOptions(this);
    frmOptionsJeux.Show();
```

And then in your second form constructor set it to private variable:

```
private Form1 parent
public frmOptions(Form1 formRef)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            // Sets the value of the Numeric UpDowns (boiteNbLignes & boiteNbColonnes

            // nbLignesDansTableauDeJeu & nbColonnesDansTableauDeJeu are the two integers I need to modify.

            boiteNbLignes.Value = frmJeu.nbLignesDansTableauDeJeu;
            boiteNbColonnes.Value = frmJeu.nbColonnesDansTableauDeJeu;
            parent = formRef;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know why we have to set Form1 to private?

Comment: @Mthb54 You don't ***have*** to. Read up on access modifiers